# Having more than one JQuery function

Tags: jquery

Depending on which one of these JQuery functions I have above the other, the one on the bottom breaks.  I was wondering if anyone would know why?  Is there something that cannot be called more than once?  I'm not a strong coder and any help is appreciated.

```
$( "#dialog-new" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  fluid: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Clear Form": function() {
      clearForm($("#newapsform"));

    },
    "Create Request": function() {

      if(formIsOkay($("#newapsform")))
      {
        $.ajax
        ({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "system/aps2.newrequest.php",  
          data: $("#newapsform").serialize(),  
          success: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#goodmsg").html("Created photo request successfully!");
            $('#goodmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);

            datatables.fnDraw();
            searchtables.fnDraw();
            phototables.fnDraw();
            clearForm($("#newapsform"));
          },
          error: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#badmsg").html("Could not create request: Use the force next time.");
            $('#badmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
          }

        });
      }
    }
  }
}); 



$( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  fluid: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Clear Static Form": function() {
      clearForm($(".statform"));

    },
    "Create Static Request": function() {

      if(formIsOkay($(".statform")))
      {
        $.ajax
        ({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "system/aps2.newrequeststatic.php",  
          data: $(".statform").serialize(),  
          success: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#goodmsg").html("Created photo request successfully!");
            $('#goodmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);

            datatables.fnDraw();
            searchtables.fnDraw();
            phototables.fnDraw();
            clearForm($(".statform"));
          },
          error: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#badmsg").html("Could not create request: Use the force next time.");
            $('#badmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
          }

        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Saying it "breaks" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I don't get any errors.  The button to submit my form in the dialog box just breaks and no longer works.  Oddly enough, the clear form button continues to work though.

Comment: Is this on document ready? Function? Post some HTML so we can see how these are being called.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.  But I believe its after document is ready.